# Div wont extend to bottom of its contents when divs inside it are floated left

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 2 divs as columns, both are floated left and set to clear none. Their container div has a background image at the top, so the background is at the top of both columns.

I want to be able to also have a background image at the bottom of the columns. Ive created another div which sits inside the container div (but outside the columns) and set a background image to its bottom.

The problem is that this div doesn't extend to the bottom of the columns it contains. How can I make it do this? Ive tried playing around with floats and clearing but without any luck.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, I hadn't noticed but id set the height of one of the containers when I was wire-framing and forgotten it was there. Removing the height and floating the right div fixed this for me.

Thanks anyway.

Comment: You should accept your own answer if you fixed it yourself, to mark the question as answered.

Comment: I cant except it for 8 more hours. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the techniques the others already mentioned, you can add `overflow:hidden` to the parent container's style.

This is a very well known CSS quirk: here is a complete treatment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
div#test {
    min-height:100%;
    background-image: url('http://www.google.nl/images/logos/ps_logo2.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom;
}

div#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="test">Blalalalalala</div>
</div>
```

This way you're div (#test) will have the height of his parent (#wrapper).
http://jsfiddle.net/F95xN/6/
Try removing the `min-height: 100%;` and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

Float elements do not count towards the height of a non-float elements. You can make the container div expand to include these floats in a couple ways:

- Add `float: left` to the container div, too.
- Or, add something like `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` to the end of the container div.
- Or, use a more flexible [clearfix technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best).